# Symfony and custom form type and input name

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form with custom type.

My custom type is like this :

```
<?php

namespace CpayCore\AppBundle\Form;

use ActorChecker\ActorChecker;
use CpayEntity\EntityBundle\Model\PaymentMethodEnum;
use CpayEntity\EntityBundle\Repository\ActorWalletRepository;
use CpayTools\ElasticsearchBundle\Form\Extension\ElasticConditionTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class PaymentMethodType extends AppAbstractType
{


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {

        $builder->add('test', ChoiceType::class, [
            self::CHOICES => PaymentMethodEnum::getAllTypes(),
            self::CHOICE_LABEL => function ($value) {
                if ($value === PaymentMethodEnum::SCT_TRANSACTION) {
                    return 'payment_request.payment_method.' . PaymentMethodEnum::WIRE_TRANSFER;
                }

                return 'payment_request.payment_method.' . $value;
            },
            self::PLACEHOLDER => self::NONE_SELECTED,
            self::LABEL => 'payment_request.payment_method',
            self::LABEL_ATTR => [
                self::E_CLASS => self::CONTROL_LABEL,
            ],
            self::TRANSLATION_DOMAIN => self::APPBUNDLE,
            self::MULTIPLE => true,
            self::EXPANDED => true,
            self::ATTR => [
                self::E_CLASS => 'checkbox-col-3',
            ],
        ]);

     

    }

}
```

In my form type I call my custom type like this :

```
 $builder->add('payment', PaymentMethodType::class, [           
        ])
```

How can I define de name of my select in template render, I won't have `[payment][test]` but only `[test]` ?

Thanks

PS : sorry for my very bad english

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only modifying the *options* array of the custom form type (and you only have *one* child), you would be better to simply extend the existing ChoiceType.

```php
class PaymentMethodType extends AppAbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            self::CHOICES => PaymentMethodEnum::getAllTypes(),
            self::CHOICE_LABEL => function ($value) {
                if ($value === PaymentMethodEnum::SCT_TRANSACTION) {
                    return 'payment_request.payment_method.' . PaymentMethodEnum::WIRE_TRANSFER;
                }

                return 'payment_request.payment_method.' . $value;
            },
            self::PLACEHOLDER => self::NONE_SELECTED,
            self::LABEL => 'payment_request.payment_method',
            self::LABEL_ATTR => [
                self::E_CLASS => self::CONTROL_LABEL,
            ],
            self::TRANSLATION_DOMAIN => self::APPBUNDLE,
            self::MULTIPLE => true,
            self::EXPANDED => true,
            self::ATTR => [
                self::E_CLASS => 'checkbox-col-3',
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }
}
```

Then, when you do

```php
 $builder->add('payment', PaymentMethodType::class, [           
        ])
```

your form will have only `myform[payment]` (but no test)

[Here is the Symfony Documentation on the subject](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-form-types-based-on-symfony-built-in-types)

Answer (score -1):

You can set the "name" empty of your form like this:

```
class PaymentMethodType extends ... 
{
    ... 

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```